# How to Hide select option list dependent from select option using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hallo guys i ve some problem in jquery to hide option from select option list, it work in  but not work in option. Like this :

```
<label>Province</label>
<select class="form-control" name="province" id="province">
        <option value="prov001"> Prov 001</option>
        <option value="prov002"> Prov 002</option>
        <option value="prov003"> Prov 003</option>              
</select>

<label>City</label>
<select class="form-control" name="city" id="city">
        <option class="cty" id="prov001" value="city001"> City 001</option>
        <option class="cty" id="prov002" value="city002"> City 002</option>
        <option class="cty" id="prov003" value="city003"> City 003</option>
        <option class="cty" id="prov001" value="city004"> City 004</option>
        <option class="cty" id="prov002" value="city005"> City 005</option>
        <option class="cty" id="prov003" value="city006"> City 001</option> 
</select>
```

and this the jquery :

```
$(function() {
    $('#province').change(function(){
        $('.cty').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

before this i use in div works but in option not, thanks

Comment: This isn't ajax it's jquery.

Comment: It's working for me.. http://jsbin.com/musove/edit?html,js,output

Comment: ok thanks @zoubida13

Comment: Are sure @MoshFeu? Are the all city option displayed? Me Not, only one option displayed : )

Comment: look at my answer - theres only one displayed cos there are multiple id's

Comment: You are right, I thought that the ids are continue. The @gavgrif 's answer seems to be the right answer.

Comment: Ok thanks @MoshFeu, for your atention and response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the select list options, you have multiple id's that are the same - you need to change these to be classes and modify the js:

```js
//js
$(function() {
    $('#province').change(function(){
        $('.cty').hide();
        $('.' + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Province</label>
<select class="form-control" name="province" id="province">
        <option value="prov001"> Prov 001</option>
        <option value="prov002"> Prov 002</option>
        <option value="prov003"> Prov 003</option>              
</select>

<select class="form-control" name="city" id="city">
        <option class="cty prov001" value="city001"> City 001</option>
        <option class="cty prov002" value="city002"> City 002</option>
        <option class="cty prov003" value="city003"> City 003</option>
        <option class="cty prov001" value="city004"> City 004</option>
        <option class="cty prov002" value="city005"> City 005</option>
        <option class="cty prov003" value="city006"> City 001</option> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

its better to use data attribute other than have multiple elements with same id.

also your question is about jQuery not Ajax.

```
<label>Province</label>
<select class="form-control" name="province" id="province">
    <option value=""> All City</option>
    <option value="prov001"> Prov 001</option>
    <option value="prov002"> Prov 002</option>
    <option value="prov003"> Prov 003</option>
</select>

<label>City</label>
<select class="form-control" name="city" id="city">
    <option class="cty" data-id="prov001" value="city001"> City 001</option>
    <option class="cty" data-id="prov002" value="city002"> City 002</option>
    <option class="cty" data-id="prov003" value="city003"> City 003</option>
    <option class="cty" data-id="prov001" value="city004"> City 004</option>
    <option class="cty" data-id="prov002" value="city005"> City 005</option>
    <option class="cty" data-id="prov003" value="city006"> City 001</option>
</select>

$(function () {
    $('#province').change(function () {
        var $item = $(this);
        var id = $item.val();
        if (id === "") {
           $(".cty").show();
        } else {
           $(".cty").hide();
           $(".cty[data-id='" + id + "']").show();
        }
     });
 });
```